Accessing windows serial com port through linux docker container
Im currently writing a C# program that listen on a serial com port using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class.
I need to run this program on a linux docker container and be able to access the serial device on my machine.
I was under the impression that it was possible to achieve this following this post:
Docker - a way to give access to a host USB or serial device?
Unfortunately, i havn't been able to make it work after following the steps provided in the post.
Any way i setup my container, i always get the same error:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the port 'COM5' is denied.
System.IO.IOException: No such file or directory

It is as if my container simply cannot see my host devices
Here is some information that might be useful
My serial device appear under COM5 in device manager and it appear under ttyS4 when i run the following bash command on my local machine.
ls -l /dev

All the commands i tried to run my container is the following:
docker run -t -i --name scannerscale -d -p 5073:5073 --privileged -e Audiences__0=http://localhost:8080 --restart always <mycontainer>

docker run -t -i --name scannerscale -d -p 5073:5073 --device=/dev/ttyS4 -e Audiences__0=http://localhost:8080 --restart always <mycontainer>

docker run -t -i --name scannerscale -d -p 5073:5073 --privileged --device=/dev/ttyS4 -e Audiences__0=http://localhost:8080 --restart always <mycontainer>

docker run -t -i --name scannerscale -d -p 5073:5073 --privileged --device=/dev/ttyS4:/dev/ttyS4 -e Audiences__0=http://localhost:8080 --restart always <mycontainer>

docker run -t -i --name scannerscale -d -p 5073:5073 --privileged --device=/dev/ttyS4:/dev/ttyS4 -v /dev:/dev -e Audiences__0=http://localhost:8080 --restart always <mycontainer>

So on and so forth.. Alot of trial and error and always the same result
I use docker desktop 4.35.1
Here is the content of my dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5073
EXPOSE 5073

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ScannerScale.Api/ScannerScale.Api.csproj", "ScannerScale.Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ScannerScale.Api/ScannerScale.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ScannerScale.Api"
RUN dotnet build "ScannerScale.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ScannerScale.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ScannerScale.Api.dll"]

Please, let me know if i missed important informations
